# How to put two dimensional array into mysql_query in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

The question in simple.

**What i have and what's the problem?**
I do have two dimensional array `$someArray[][]`. The first bracket i could put "subject" or "date". The second one, goes from 1 to 4 (just an example - `$someArray['date'][0]`)

Now when i try to get some data from database with `mysql_query()` i have some problems. I am trying to use this two dimensional array in WHERE part in query.

**Examples what works and what doesn't**
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT some from table where date='$someArray[date][0]' AND subject='$someArray[subject][0]') or die(mysql_error());`

When i use this, it doesn't return me anything. But when i first assing those values to new variables:

`$variable1 = $someArray['date'][0];`
`$variable2 = $someArray['subject'][0];`

and then use them in query

`` `$result = mysql_query("SELECT some from table where date='$variable1' AND subject='$variable2') or die(mysql_error()); ``

It works like a charm.

**Question**
Whats wrong with my first query, am I writing those arrays wrong? I get no errors.
Tried to put single apostrophes inside [] brackets in mysql query, but then i do get errors. Also it works without them if i use array like: `$someotherArray[somedata]` in query.

Comment: Please change your code not to use `mysql_ ` functions anymore. That is deprecated functionality in PHP and will be removed. Look at red block on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. Change to mysqli or PDO for safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array interpolation only works for a single level of subscripting. For multidimensional arrays, you need to use `{...}` wrappers:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT some from table where date='{$someArray['date'][0]}' AND subject='{$someArray['subject'][0]}') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in the query is lacking a closing double quote. And concat the string in stead of just adding it within. The string parser doesn't like arrays, multi dimensional.

Solution:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT some from table where date='".$someArray[date][0]."' AND subject='".$someArray[subject][0]."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And like @barmar mentioned brackets also work

On a side note, make sure you escape the data to make sure SQL injection is prevented!